# How can I keep input values of React Material UI multiple select after refreshing/reloading the page?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react material ui multi-select that shows the list of all my venues and I can multi-select venues from it. Right now when I refresh the page after multi select, all my selections disappear and the selected list shows nothing; but I want it to keep the selected values after page refresh/reload.  Here is my code:

```
const addEventContent = () => {
  const venueNames = venues.map((item) => item.name);
  const venueIds = venues.map((item) => item.id);
  const names = {};
  venueIds.forEach((key, i) => (names[key] = venueNames[i]));
  return(
   <>
    .
    .
    .
          <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel id='demo-mutiple-checkbox-label'>Venues</InputLabel>
              <Select
                  labelId='demo-mutiple-chip-label'
                  id='demo-mutiple-chip'
                  multiple
                  value={venueId}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  input={<Input id='select-multiple-chip' />}
                  renderValue={(selected) => (
                  <div className={classes.chips}>
                     {selected.map((value) => (
                       <Chip
                        key={value}
                        label={names[value]}
                        className={classes.chip}
                        />
                        ))}
                   </div>
                  )}
                 >
                  {Object.keys(names).map((id) => (
                    <MenuItem key={id} value={id}>
                      {names[id]}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
           </FormControl>
   .
   .
   .
  <>
}
const handleChange = (event) => setVenueId(event.target.value);
```

I would appreciate any help or hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `localStorage` to store such values that persist over refresh. Other than using the browser provided storage, I am not sure there is a way to persist such data over the client side after reloads.

You can add another function as follows:

```
function getVenueId() {
  const localStorage = window.localStorage;
  let venueId;

  if(localStorage) {
    localStorage.getItem('venue-id-selected-value');
  }
  return venueId;
}
```

When you initialize `venueId` using `useState`, you can call this function as follows:

```
let [venueId, setVenueId] = useState(getVenueId());
```

And finally, in your `handleChange` function, you can just set the item in localStorage to the selected value as follows:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const localStorage = window.localStorage;
  localStorage.setItem('venue-if-selected-value',`${event.target.value}`);
  setVenueId(event.target.value);
}
```

Note the caveats of this approach:

=> You can only store string values in `localStorage`.

=> `localStorage` data is specific to the protocol of the webpage.

Edit: If you are looking for a solution that does not have to persist over a long period of time, such as only until the tab is closed, the `sessionStorage` may be a better option for you. The solution would still be the same mostly. You would just have to replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage` in the code.